# Join specific row on null LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

I have two tables **items** and **users**.

I want to create view with owners and they managers, directors etc. of the specific items.

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT Name, OwnerId, owner.FirstName, manager.FirstName
FROM items
LEFT JOIN users as owner ON owner.id = OwnerId
LEFT JOIN users as manager ON manager.id = owner.ManagerId
```

Now some items are old and OwnerId is outdated (user no longer exists in table) so LEFT JOIN returns NULL.

I want to assign specific user from the **users** table in that case.

```
SELECT Name, OwnerId, owner.FirstName, manager.FirstName
FROM items
LEFT JOIN users as owner 
  ON owner.id = OwnerId --WHEN owner is null THEN owner ON owner.id = (SELECT * FROM users WHERE Id = 123)
LEFT JOIN users as manager ON manager.id = owner.ManagerId
```

Is it possible? I want to do it like this, so i don't have to update manager, director, etc. manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a default value using another `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT i.Name, i.OwnerId,
       COALESCE(uo.FirstName, ud.FirstName) as owner_firstname,
       um.FirstName as manager_firstname
FROM items i LEFT JOIN
     users uo
     ON uo.id = i.OwnerId LEFT JOIN
     users ud
     ON ud.id = 123 LEFT JOIN
     users um
     ON um.id = COALESCE(uo.ManagerId, ud.ManagerId);
```

Notes:

- This also uses the default for the manager name.
- The `SELECT` distinguishes between the two names being returned.
- Your table aliases are fine, but table abbreviations are easier to type.
- You should fix your data model, so you don't have dangling ids.  First declare foreign key relationships.  Second, you might want to consider "soft" deletes (setting a flag) rather than actually deleting a row.